# Issue with AngularJS and 3G conneciton

Tags: angularjs, http, 3g

I developed an AngularJS and I have a issue I can't fix, in a desktop the app works fine and in a mobile with Wi-Fi connection too.

But when I use it in a mobile with 3G connection it fails 'cause it doesn't do a GET request to the server, I've thought it was the cache but I disabled it in app config ($http.defaults.cache = false) and it doesn't work.

I have three nested request, one POST and two GET in order to refresh the shown data. The request in what I have the issue is the first GET, it doesn´t send the request to the server but treat the response as it had returned 200 OK.

Example code:

```
sendData()
.then(refreshFirstData) (problem here)
.then(refreshSecondData);
```

Does anyone know what can be happening?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I could get a capture from the request when using 3G connection and it loads the data from cache... I think I disabled this option..

[image]

**SOLUTION**

I found the solution in nginx, I needed to add 'expires -1' to the config of my site.

Comment: Can you capture the raw response with 200 status?

Comment: No... form the mobile I can't capture it...I can see is the log of the server and the request is never performed.

Comment: add an error handler

Comment: Actually I have an error handler